Intermittent false 'paper jam' message on HP5540 series 'Envy' printer
I have an HP Envy 5540 series printer. It has started complaining of 'paper jam' when I send it printouts, but there is no jam. When I confirm that I have cleared the 'jam' (I have in fact done nothing!) the printer cancels my print job, but then prints the next request without complaint.
How can I resolve this annoying intermittent issue?

Could be that the incoming paper feed roller is not quite catching a sheet? First sensor says "there's a sheet at the roller" then the next says "I've not seen a sheet" and the printer assumes a jam... Next time you try to print everything shifts to feed a sheet again and the page catches it and feeds properly...

On other printers, I'd occasionally need to clean the rollers with isopropanol to get rid of dirt and glaze.

I once had a small plastic that had broken off and fallen in that caused weird paper jams.  If you look for paper, you almost always miss anything else.
